# java.util.Comparator does not take type parameters

Tags: java, scala, akka

I've incorporated Akka into my project by adding this line to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.3.14"
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

```
/var/folders/d8/dxrq0j_d10s7twghyd6v5tdr0000gn/T/sbt_90d70183/xsbt/ExtractAPI.scala:479: error: java.util.Comparator does not take type parameters
  private[this] val sortClasses = new Comparator[Symbol] {
```

Now, I know that this error has been reported here https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1399 and has a solution described here https://1bitentropy.wordpress.com/2014/12/29/scala-errors-with-jdk-1-8-in-intellij/.

The problem with the solution is that it's suggesting to use JDK 1.7 rather than JDK 1.8. However, I can't switch from Java 8.

Taking into account that the above solution was given in 2014, have there been any other developments such as bug fixes  in newer versions which allow the error to be solved without switching to Java 7?

Answer (score 0):

From your links, I readthis comment, and I confirm, this works for me.

> Humoyun commented on 23 Feb 2016
>
> updating to 2.10.4 resolved comparator issue for me too